# Error in loading font

Tags: fonts, errors

I have MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.5.2 installed on a Windows 7 64bit OS. I have downloaded a latex template from http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=tetn20&page=instructions. I was given the error

```
"Font U/bbold/m/n/12=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/9=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/6=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/7=bbold7 at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/5=bbold5 at 5.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/8=bbold8 at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \maketitle 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/8=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \section{Introduction} 
"Font U/bbold/m/n/5=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found \section{Introduction}
```

when trying to compile the file. How can I fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) You can format code or equivalents by using the {} button in the edit window or by indenting lines with four spaces

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.